# cakephp and phpunit 9

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I need a confirmation and your feedback about phpunit version.

In cakephp [documention](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#installing-phpunit), the 8.5 release is suggested.

I have launched my tests with PHPUnit 9.5.21 and all seems to be OK, but perhaps there are some drawback I've did not seen ?

I use PHP 8.1.5.

Thanks for your feedback about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs aren't always up do date with the latest and greatest stuff in every single aspect, as it kinda needs to cover the major version. As far as PHPUnit goes, version `^9.3` is officially supported as of CakePHP 4.2.

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.2.0/composer.json#L58-L63**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.2.0/composer.json#L14-L20**